# Counting table row tags in text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to count how many starting table row tags `<tr>` that would be in the following text. Keep in mind that I said text, not html. I get this data back in a textarea (don't ask) and I need to count how many starting tr tags are in this textarea. How would I do that? Whats the appropriate method in jquery to achieve this?

```
<textarea name='details' id='details'>
    <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th></th>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do:

```
var temp =$('#details').val();
var count = temp.match(/<tr[^>]*>/gi);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FdpnJ/3/)

now count  `<tr > <tr class=""> <TR>`

Comment: What if there was <tr > ? It wouldn't get counted ...  http://jsfiddle.net/FdpnJ/1/

Comment: it would only count <tr> not <tr > or <tr class=''>

Comment: That is not very complete, is it? :)

Comment: wowzuzz asked for <tr> on a textarea if you want any tr roasted answer should work

Comment: What do the characters [^>]* mean?

Comment: [^>] mean anything but '>' and *> repeat until '>'

Answer (score 4):

You should wrap your text in a jquery object and then use length property:

```
var myText = $.trim($('#details').val());
var numberTRs = $(myText).find('tr').length;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FdpnJ/2/) ©Blake Plumb 2013 ;)